# What do firebugs do when they "connect" by their rear?

Tags: zoology

See [this image](http://static.baubau.bg/resources/razmnojavane-pri-velikdencheto.jpg) for example.

What are they doing? What is the name of this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mate!

These matings can be very long

> When copulating, firebugs (Pyrrhocoris apterus) form tandems for prolonged periods. Half of the copulations of marked individuals in the field lasted longer than 12 h, and some lasted up to 7 days. ([Schöfl and Taborsky (2002)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00265-002-0524-9))

The likely reason for such a long mating is for males to guard the female to prevent future matings and therefore to prevent sperm competition

> males prolong copulations as a form of ejaculate-guarding under high competition with other males. ([Schöfl and Taborsky (2002)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00265-002-0524-9))